# Excel - How can I extract unique values from one column to an another column without using array formulas and helper columns?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, unique, extract

I have one sheet named student list that contains 'Job Title' column and I want to extract unique values from that column to an another column in a different sheet but the condition is NOT to use array formulas and helper columns.

Comment: Show your data and expected output. What you tried till now?

Comment: Your question is like a riddle. Without VBA I can understand. Without array formulas is an imposition. How do I open a can of beer with one hand? Is this a task for your school?

Answer (score 2):

Use following formula `(Non Array)` to extract unique values from a list.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($C$4:$C$20,MATCH(0,INDEX(COUNTIF($E$3:E3,$C$4:$C$20),0,0),0)),"")
```

[image]